# Change cursor in GL fullscreen on OSX using cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, macos, opengl, fullscreen, nsview

Can anyone provide a sample / link to a sample Cocoa app that changes the 'hardware' cursor in a fullscreen OpenGL Cocoa app?  I have been able to create a full screen GL app and an app that changes the cursor by overriding NSView::resetCursorRects but I have not been able to get both to work simultaneously.  I've also refitted some of the Apple GL samples (CocoaGL, Custom Cocoa OpenGL, etc) by overriding NSView::resetCursorRects and I haven't been able to get the cursor to change in fullscreen in them either.  I have the book "OpenGL Programming on Mac OS X" which also avoids the problem.

@Christopher: I hadn't tried [NSCursor set].  Good call but I made a run at it and no luck.  It still returns to the system cursor.  I'd say that perhaps something is overriding it in my calls that switch to fullscreen but I've actually tried reseting the mouse cursor in my NSView's draw routine (which gets called repeatedly) and the cursor never switches from the system default.

Answer (score 1):

Try using NSCursor directly, the NSView cursor rect methods depend on things such as a properly sized and visible NSWindow to work properly which aren't necessarily the case in full screen mode.